# Regular expression in javascript to remove (back)slashes before and after

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression to remove slashes before and after a string in javascript:

```
("/////asdf//////").replace(/([\\\/]*)(\w+.*\w+)([\\\/]*)/, "$2")
```

It works fine for strings:

> ////m///\\9\///m////
>
> m/9//////
>
> m9//////
>
> /m9/

But it doesn't work for this example:

> /////////m//////////

What would be the best regular expression for this job? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```js
let str = "/////asdf//////";

str = str.replace(/^\/*|\/*$/g, '');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: One thing about `/^\/*|\/*$/g` pattern: it will try to replace empty strings with empty strings. Use `+` instead of `*` quantifiers to make it only replace non-empty matches.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var s = "/////m//////////////////";

console.log(s.replace(/(^\/+)|(\/+$)/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this :

```js
var rgx = /(\/*)(.*[^/])(\/*)/;

console.log(("/////asdf//////").replace(rgx, "$2"));
console.log(("////m///\\9\///m////").replace(rgx, "$2"));
console.log(("m/9//////").replace(rgx, "$2"));
console.log(("m9//////").replace(rgx, "$2"));
console.log(("/m9/").replace(rgx, "$2"));
console.log(("/////////m//////////").replace(rgx, "$2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex requires at least 2 word chars. Make the second one optional:

```
/([\\\/]*)(\w+(?:.*\w+)?)([\\\/]*)/
               ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nDuYp8/1)

The `(?:.*\w+)?` matches 1 or 0 occurrence of any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then 1 or more word chars.

If you need to only remove the slashes at the start/end of the string, use

```
.replace(/^[\\\/]+|[\\\/]+$/g, "")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CEBaIt/1).

**Details**

- `^[\\\/]+` - start of string (`^`) and then 1 or more `/` or/and `\` chars
- `|` - or
- `[\\\/]+$` - 1 or more `/` or/and `\` and then end of string.

Note that `g` modifier is obligatory to make sure both leading and trailing slashes get removed.